# How to run simple .net core console app with AWS fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Currently, I have one .net core console application which takes around 3-4 hours for completion. I need to move this piece of code to AWS Fargate. I am seeing the examples of .net core Web or API Hosted on AWS Fragate but not sure how to deploy and Host console applications on AWS Fargate.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I have one .net core console application which takes around 3-4 hours
>   for completion

Seems like you need Schedule based task, as you are not running the fargate service, as you do not need to run again and again once task complete, so you can have two option for such task.

> For Schedule rule type, choose whether to use a fixed interval
>   schedule or a cron expression for your schedule rule. For more
>   information, see Schedule Expressions for Rules in the Amazon
>   CloudWatch Events User Guide.
>
> - For Run at fixed interval, enter the interval and unit for your
>     schedule.
> - For Cron expression, enter the cron expression for your task schedule.
>     These expressions have six required fields, and fields are separated
>     by white space. For more information, and examples of cron
>     expressions, see Cron Expressions in the Amazon CloudWatch Events User
>     Guide.

[scheduled_tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/scheduled_tasks.html)

As far your second question,

> AWS Fargate but not sure how to deploy and Host console applications
>   on AWS Fargate

Fargate has nothing to do with the application, just build the docker-image and push the image ECR. Fargate will take care of it.

The most important thing is logging, you will not able to see logs of your container, you need to push container logs to cloud watch.

[image]

[using_awslogs with fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/using_awslogs.html)

You can check further below links

[aws-fargate-features-docker](https://www.infinitypp.com/amazon-aws/aws-fargate-features-docker/)

[hosting-asp-net-core-applications-in-amazon-ecs-using-aws-fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/hosting-asp-net-core-applications-in-amazon-ecs-using-aws-fargate/)

[deployment-ecs-aspnetcore-fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-ecs-aspnetcore-fargate.html)